# Can I use canonical tag for this?

Tags: seo, rel-canonical

I have page with video content at URL:

```
domain.com/video/id
```

also I have video info in clickable popup with the own url:

```
domain.com/video/id/info
```

this popup `domain.com/video/id/info` have same content like `domain.com/video/id` only with several sentences different, I think to add canonical tag to avoid possible google penalty

```
<link rel="canonical" href="domain.com/video/id" />
```

to

```
domain.com/video/id/info
```

Is this a good or bad idea?

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
<link rel="canonical" href="domain.com/video/id" />
```

Needs to be in both the pages

`domain.com/video/id`
and
`domain.com/video/id/info`

That's how canonical works.  Even then, it's a suggestion to Google.  It can choose to differ.

So another way would be to not index one of them.  Put this in on one of the pages

```
<meta name='robots' content='noindex'>
```

Answer (score -1):

task: it means that he gets a duplicate of the content, at static addresses, but the second address is a popup. at the same time, he wants to make a canonical on a pop-up, from the primary address for placing video content

difficulties. if it's a popup, where does it get its static address from? those. the error may be that it will start to canonicalize a normal page on the Popup window, this is a mistake. better not to do that

reality. BUT, if he calls Popup just opening an extended page with info in a separate window at a separate address (through _blank for example), then yes, it will be correct to put the canonical, but then there is an error in the code

implementation. you need to canonical domain.com/video/id TO domain.com/video/id/info , so the code will be `<link rel="canonical" href="domain.com/video/id/info" />` . and you need to put it on the page `domain.com/video/id`

result. by doing so, you will redirect the weight of the page and visitors from the search results from domain.com/video/id to domain.com/video/id/info

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).